# is there any way to get last activity from CMMotionActivityManager

Tags: ios, core-motion

```
-(void)queryActivityStartingFromDate:(NSDate *)start
                           toDate:(NSDate *)end
                          toQueue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue
                      withHandler:(CMMotionActivityQueryHandler)handler;
```

This API may return empty activities if startDate and endDate very close.

I wanna get activity in timestamp.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255533/how-to-use-cmmotionactivitymanager-and-receive-updates , Check this may help you.